# Exponential Generating Function for Dirichlet Character

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, number-theory, generating-functions, dirichlet-character

I am working on a differential equation problem, and have ended up with the following form:

$$g(x; N) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\chi_0(n)}{n!} x^n,$$

with $\chi_0(n)$ the principal Dirichlet character mod $N$.

It is clear that this is equivalent to

$$g(x; N) = \sum_{(n,\,N) \, = \, 1} \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

I am trying to determine if the function is periodic, i.e. $$\forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists T \in \mathbb{C}, g(x + T; N) = g(x; N).$$
It is a sort of cut up exponential function. Is there a known name for this function? Or otherwise an arithmetic closed form?

Thank you,

Jackson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $N$ is a power of $2$, then $g(x; N) = \sinh x$, which is periodic with period $T = 2\pi i$, so we will ignore this case.

Let $P_N(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} a_j x^j$ be the unique polynomial of degree at most $N-1$ whose value at every primitive $N^{th}$ root of unity is $1$, and whose value at all other $N^{th}$ roots of unity is $0$ (use Lagrange interpolation, for example). Put $\zeta = \exp(2\pi i/N)$. Then

$$\begin{array}{rcl} 
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} a_j \exp(\zeta^j x) & = & \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} a_j \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\zeta^{jk} x^k}{k!} \\ 
& = & \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} a_j \zeta^{jk} \\ 
& = & g(x; N) 
\end{array}$$
since by definition $\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} a_j \zeta^{jk} = 0$ if $k$ is not relatively prime to $N$, and equals $1$ if $k$ is relatively prime to $N$.

For $T$ to be a period, this requires

$$\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} a_j \exp(\zeta^j T) \exp(\zeta^j x) = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} a_j \exp(\zeta^j x).$$
By linear independence of exponential functions (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451281/showing-that-n-exponential-functions-are-linearly-independent); the only thing needed is that the $\zeta^j$ are distinct), this forces $a_j \exp(\zeta^j T) = a_j$ for $j = 0, 1, \ldots, N-1$. This forces $\zeta^j T \in 2\pi i \mathbb{Z}$ for all $j$ such that $a_j \neq 0$. Assuming the existence of a period $T \neq 0$, this in turn forces $\zeta^j$ to be a rational multiple of $\zeta^k$ whenever $a_j, a_k$ are nonzero, and the only way that can happen is when $\zeta^j = \pm \zeta^k$.

This puts severe constraints on what $P_N(x)$ can be. For example, $P_N(x)$ can have no more than two monomial terms, and the powers of $x$ in those terms must differ by $N/2$ in view of the $\zeta^j = \pm \zeta^k$ relation. This rules out $N$ being odd, for instance. (To return briefly to the case $N = 2^m$, there one has $P_N(x) = -\frac1{2}(x^{N/2} - 1)$.) So, assuming a period exists, $P_N(x)$ is of type $ax^k + b x^{k + N/2}$. Ultimately, the strain becomes too great for any $N$ but a power of $2$, because for instance it implies

$$a + b(\zeta^j)^{N/2} = 0$$
for each $j$ not relatively prime to $N$, meaning $\zeta^{jN/2} = -a/b$ for all such $j$, which is absurd: it would mean $\zeta^{jN/2} = -1$ for all such $j$. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: The linear independence was exactly the step I needed and that I was missing.

Comment: Cf. also linear independence of characters of a group $G$. I enjoyed working out this problem. I also posed a follow-up question (see the linked question, which currently has no upvotes), asking what is known about this $P_N(x)$, and which I'm vaguely thinking is connected with cyclotomic polynomials.